# Appcache does not work: Manifest fetch failed (404)

Tags: html, caching, web, offline-caching

I'm having problems with appcache and manifest file for my website.

**demo.appcache file:**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/img/logoSmallSmall.png
/crosshair.html
```

**HTML that I am trying to cache:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="demo.appcache">
<head>
    <title>crosshairs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>katse</h1>
        <img src="img/logoSmallSmall.png" alt="image text" onclick="javascript:alert('Your popup message');" /> 
        <div style="display: none;">sdsd</div>
        <img src="img/logoSmallSmall.png" alt="image text" onclick="javascript:alert('Your popup message2');" /> 
        <div style="display: none;">sdsd</div>
        <img src="img/logoSmallSmall.png" alt="image text" onclick="javascript:alert('Your popup message3');" /> 
        <div style="display: none;">sdsd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Added this line into .htaccess:**

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

**Javascript console on Chrome gives me such error:**

```
Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (404)
```

Could someone help me to fix it?

Comment: what does your directory structure look like? Where is the .appcache file located?

Comment: .appcache is located in the same directory where my HTML file is.

Comment: If you hit the manifest url directly does it load "http://yoursite.tld/demo.manifest" ? Also, have you tried this tool? http://manifest-validator.com/

Comment: I just got help from one friend, I found out that my problem is that my web does not find this demo.appcache file.
To fix it I must do the following: 
This can be fixed by R-clicking on the c.appcache in VS and making the build action on the file "content".
But I have no idea how to use Visual Studio to do that.
Also I needed to add come to web.config file in my VM of azure, but I cant find that config file anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that whole problem was because of the file name.
All you have to do is name the file: cache.manifest , this is all you have to do

Comment: I would like to know exactly why this fixed the issue, my guess is that it has something to do with IIS setup of mime types etc .... but I cannot put my finger on the exact setting.